# Angular Material Custom Class Button Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-material

I am trying to write a custom class for angular material button, but there is one issue with that, when I click on the button and move away(minimize or activate another window) from the browser, it fades out or makes it white and when I click on the browser window then it turns to proper shape/color, don't know the reason but how to control this does any one have any idea.
My Css Class:

```css
.DeleteBtn.md-raised {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #CC090F;
  text-transform: initial;
  min-width: 88px;
  margin: 6px 0px;
  max-width: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.DeleteBtn.md-raised:not([disabled]):hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7F0509;
  max-width: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<md-button class="md-raised DeleteBtn">Delete</md-button>
```

[image]

Comment: seems on ':focus' or ':active' your button inherits default css!! inspect properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing base CSS class for all  components `.md-button`. Here is a working CSS snippet:

```
.md-button.DeleteBtn.md-raised:not([disabled]).md-focused,.md-button.DeleteBtn.md-raised {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #CC090F;
  text-transform: initial;
  min-width: 88px;
  margin: 6px 0px;
  max-width: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.md-button.DeleteBtn.md-raised:not([disabled]):hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7F0509;
  max-width: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

I would recommend to read more about `<md-button>` [CSS](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/button) and follow best practices. Also here is a working example for you:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybdzZJ
Hope that will help you. Good luck :)

Comment: **dim0_0n**, you open your codepen and click on the button and minimize the windows and then open the window you see its color is white???

Comment: @Saleem go ahead and check it now

Comment: **dim0_0n**, lovely, I will add the same. Thanks